# MariaDB service crashes since updating to Laravel 11 oom-kill possible memory leak in Laravel 11?

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

Duplicating over to here as advised by Laravel

#### Laravel Version

11.1.0

#### PHP Version

8.3.4

#### Database Driver & Version

MariaDB 10.11

#### Description

Hi :wave:

I thought I'd just mention this in case anyone else has experienced this since updating to Laravel 11.

I use MariaDB 10.11 in production. Since updating, I'm seeing that my database has been crashing. I've been running my server for a few years now, and it's always been operating on the latest Laravel version, and also has been fine sitting between 75% and 90% memory utilisation (8GB).

#### Steps To Reproduce

Two noticeable things are different in Laravel 11 compared to Laravel 10:

1. Removal of dbal package
2. Mariadb driver

I wanted to figure out whether I'm missing anything. As a result of this, at a cost, I've had to increase my server's memory. I do wonder whether there's a memory leak in how the driver works now in Laravel 11?

```
× mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.11 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: oom-kill) since Thu 2024-03-28 04:00:36 EDT; 5min ago
   Duration: 1d 1h 19min 29.156s
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 766 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 825 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 874 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mariadbd --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=killed, signal=KILL)
    Process: 1443 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 874 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
        CPU: 2h 39min 52.288s

Mar 27 02:41:07 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1473]:   1. Back-up your data before with 'mariadb-upgrade'
Mar 27 02:41:07 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1473]:   2. Start the database daemon using 'systemctl start mariadb.service'
Mar 27 02:41:07 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1473]:   3. Run 'mariadb-upgrade' with a database user that has sufficient privileges
Mar 27 02:41:07 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1473]: Read more about 'mariadb-upgrade' usage at:
Mar 27 02:41:07 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1473]: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/
Mar 27 02:41:07 domain-monitor-2022 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.11 database server.
Mar 28 04:00:36 domain-monitor-2022 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Mar 28 04:00:36 domain-monitor-2022 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Mar 28 04:00:36 domain-monitor-2022 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Mar 28 04:00:36 domain-monitor-2022 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 2h 39min 52.288s CPU time.
```

It's been almost 3 hours since rebooting my database server, and I'm seeing the memory usage here at 1GB

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.11 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-03-28 04:25:45 EDT; 2h 23min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 834 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 887 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1182 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 946 (mariadbd)
     Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
      Tasks: 95 (limit: 100205)
     Memory: 1.0G
        CPU: 15min 19.823s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
             └─946 /usr/libexec/mariadbd --basedir=/usr

Mar 28 04:25:44 domain-monitor-2022 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.11 database server...
Mar 28 04:25:44 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[887]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.
Mar 28 04:25:44 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[887]: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.
Mar 28 04:25:45 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1212]: The datadir located at /var/lib/mysql needs to be upgraded using 'mariadb-upgrade' tool. This can be done using the fo>
Mar 28 04:25:45 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1212]:   1. Back-up your data before with 'mariadb-upgrade'
Mar 28 04:25:45 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1212]:   2. Start the database daemon using 'systemctl start mariadb.service'
Mar 28 04:25:45 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1212]:   3. Run 'mariadb-upgrade' with a database user that has sufficient privileges
Mar 28 04:25:45 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1212]: Read more about 'mariadb-upgrade' usage at:
Mar 28 04:25:45 domain-monitor-2022 mariadb-check-upgrade[1212]: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/
Mar 28 04:25:45 domain-monitor-2022 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.11 database server.
```

Comment: You could test whether it is [the new Mariadb driver](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/upgrade#dedicated-mariadb-driver), by switching back to the MySQL driver.

Comment: I've retained `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` in production so should be the same as before

Comment: OK, then why not test `DB_CONNECTION=mariadb`? I agree it's unlikely to help, but it's something you'll likely want to do in the future anyway.

Comment: I would raise this as a bug report on laravel's support page, not here.

Comment: Just tried updating `DB_CONNECTION=mariadb`. Still seeing a rise in memory usage.

Comment: If you want to turn this into a programming question, you'd have to extract a [mcve]. For a bug report, this is the wrong forum. BTW: Removed the "linux" tag, see its description for why.